# Data not inserted into Sqlite database on Android OS

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

Below is my code ; I cannot insert data on button click as my program stop running  when I click  on submit button my code is as follows:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class insertData extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ContentValues c;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final EditText name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtname);
        final EditText address=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtaddress);
        final EditText policyNo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpolicyno);
        Button submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        final TextView text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        c = new ContentValues();     
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(
            "TestingData.db"
            , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
            , null
            );
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());

       // String qry="CREATE TABLE test1(name text,address text,policy text);";
       // db.execSQL(qry);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"heloo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                c.put("Name",name.getText().toString().trim());
                c.put("Address",address.getText().toString().trim());
                c.put("PolicyNo",policyNo.getText().toString().trim()); 
                db.insert("test1", null, c);


                Cursor retrive = db.query("test11",null ,null, null, null, null, null);
                retrive.moveToFirst();
                 for(int i=0;i<retrive.getCount();i++)
                 {
                     String nm = retrive.getString(1);
                     String add=retrive.getString(2);
                     String polno=retrive.getString(3);
                     text.setText(nm+" "+add+" "+polno);                     

                 }//for ends/......  
           //  retrive.close();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

I don't know what happens here; please help me.

Comment: How did you get a +1 vote for this very general question you have asked, without even a log cat output of your application?

Comment: Might be friend of OP upvoted :)...

Comment: Wesley,user1042031, don't know who have voted and no error in log cat displayed that is why not given logcat ,ohterwise i don't need to upload question

Comment: the fact that you have an `execSQL` statement in your `Activity` tells me you are doing something very wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my button click event is not assigned memory therefore declare button diffrerent as beloow so my click event detected and fired

```
public class insertData extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ContentValues c;
    Button submit;      <-------
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); sss
        final EditText name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtname);
        final EditText address=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtaddress);
        final EditText policyNo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpolicyno);
        submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
```

i dont know why but this solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted your logcat dump but the first thing I noticed was that you are creating a table named "test1" and inserting/querying data into "test11".

Comment: just ignore it that was changes i made when doing R&D i'll correct it